# How to generate a CMS (cryptographic message syntax) with Mono Framework and BouncyCastle API?

Tags: mono, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have a Certificate in PKCS#12 format and I need to generate a CMS signature (Cryptographic Message Syntax). Due that "Mono Framework" does not have a full implemented "System.Security.Cryptography" assembly, I am trying to use "Bouncy Castle API for C#".

So, using "Bouncy Castle", I need to write an alternative code to the one I had wrote on DOTNET.

The code on DOT NET is the following:

```
X509Certificate2 crt = new X509Certificate2();

byte[] crtBytes = [ certificate in the format PKCS12 (certificate + private key) obtained using FileStream class]

crt.Import(crtBytes, "123456", X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);

Encoding msgCodificado = Encoding.UTF8;

byte[] msgBytes = msgCodificado.GetBytes(xmlTRA.OuterXml); // xmlTRA.OuterXml is the data to sign

ContentInfo pkcsContentInfo = new ContentInfo(msgBytes);

SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(pkcsContentInfo);
CmsSigner firmante = new CmsSigner(crt);

firmante.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
cms.ComputeSignature(firmante); // ---> throw an cryptografy exception with MONO

byte[] firma = cms.Encode();
firmaB64 = Convert.ToBase64String(firma);
```

Anyone knows how to write an alternative code using "Bouncy Castle API for C#"?

Answer (score 0):

Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs has classes for working with a PKCS#12 store.
Org.BouncyCastle.Cms has classes for working with CMS messages.

There are corresponding test classes in the source code that show the basics of using, e.g. Pkcs12Store(Builder) and CmsSignedData(Generator).